# MySQL Chinese pinyin encoding issue

Tags: php, mysql, cjk

I have a MySQL database set to utf8. My charset/collation variables are:

> **Variable_name** | **Value**
>
> character_set_client | utf8
>
> character_set_connection | utf8
>
> character_set_database | utf8
>
> character_set_filesystem | binary
>
> character_set_results | utf8
>
> character_set_server | latin1
>
> character_set_system | utf8
>
> collation_connection | utf8_general_ci
>
> collation_database | utf8_general_ci
>
> collation_server | latin1_swedish_ci

I have a web page that displays Chinese characters and Pinyin from our MySQL DB. The Chinese characters display fine, but the Pinyin is garbled. For instance,

displays: NÃ¡njÄ«ng
correct: Nánjīng

Now, I check page encoding and it is set to UTF8. I echoed out Nánjīng in PHP and it displayed fine. I checked out the data in command line and it is correct in the database. However, whenever it is coming through a query, it garbles the pinyin, but not the Chinese characters. Anyone know why this could be happening?

Comment: Is it possible the Han characters are in UTF-8 but pinyin isn't?  You need to verify the character set per table.

Comment: Related issue, [fixing column encoding in MySQL](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/12/18/fixing-column-encoding-mess-in-mysql/)

Comment: @Steve-o Thanks for the link! That led me down the right path. I posted what I did to fix it.

Comment: `NÃ¡njÄ«ng` is Mojibake; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored for likely causes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. It was a collating issue. I modified the cnf to set the collation_server variable to utf8_general_ci, then reimported my data and it works fine... I don't know why I didn't think of that earlier.

Answer (score 2):

> if you want to store pinyin in mysql database ,you have to encode it by **base64_encode();** and at the time of display you have to encode it by **base64_decode();** and one of most important ,you have to use **header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8 general ci');** at the top of page